# Merging sets of data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

Probably a simple one.

I have this type of a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(sp1.name = c("sp1.n1",NA,"sp1.n3",NA), sp1.id = c("sp1.id1","sp1.id2",NA,NA),
                 sp2.name = c(NA,NA,"sp2.n3",NA), sp2.id = c(NA,NA,NA,"sp2.id4"),
                 sp3.name = c("sp3.n1",NA,NA,NA), sp3.id = c("sp3.id1",NA,NA,NA))
```

It is comprised of pairs of columns for each 'sp' index: `sp<index>.name` and `sp<index>.id`. In this example index is 1,2,3.

I'm looking for a way (probably through `tidyverse`) to merge, for each `sp`, its pair of corresponding name and id columns where the rules for merging are:

1. `if !is.na(sp<index>.name) & !is.na(sp<index>.id) return sp<index>.name`
2. `if !is.na(sp<index>.name) & is.na(sp<index>.id) return sp<index>.name`
3. `else if is.na(sp<index>.name) & !is.na(sp<index>.id) return sp<index>.id`
4. `else return NA`

So for this example the resulting `data.frame` is:

```
df <- data.frame(sp1 = c("sp1.n1","sp1.id2","sp1.n3",NA),
                 sp2 = c(NA,NA,"sp2.n3","sp2.id4"),
                 sp3 = c("sp3.n1",NA,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  gather(id, value, -rn) %>%
  mutate(idx = gsub("\\..*", "", id)) %>%
  group_by(idx, rn) %>%
  mutate(
    value = case_when(
      any(grepl("name", id) & !is.na(value)) & any( (grepl("id", id) & !is.na(value)) | (grepl("id", id) & is.na(value)) ) ~ value[grepl("name", id)],
      any(grepl("name", id) & is.na(value)) & any(grepl("id", id) & !is.na(value)) ~ value[grepl("id", id)],
      TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  distinct(idx, value, rn) %>%
  spread(idx, value)
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   rn [4]
     rn sp1     sp2     sp3   
  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> 
1     1 sp1.n1  NA      sp3.n1
2     2 sp1.id2 NA      NA    
3     3 sp1.n3  sp2.n3  NA    
4     4 NA      sp2.id4 NA
```